# Return value from constructed class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, operator-overloading

I'm trying to monkey with a class template that mimics the stl classes.  I'm experimenting with a currency class as a new type to better handle currency in our system.

This is a very rough draft of my experiment:

```
template <class T> class CURRENCY
{
    private:
        int p_iDollars;
        int p_iCents;
        int p_iPrecision = pow(10, 5);

    public:
        CURRENCY(T dStartingValue)
        {
            int p = this->p_iPrecision;
            double temp_dStartingValue = dStartingValue * p;
            this->p_iDollars = temp_dStartingValue / p;
            this->p_iCents = (dStartingValue - this->p_iDollars) * p;
        }

        CURRENCY operator+(T value)
        {
            this->p_iDollars = ((double) val()) + value;
        }

        CURRENCY operator-(T value)
        {
            this->p_iDollars = ((double) val()) - value;
        }

        CURRENCY operator*(T value)
        {
            this->p_iDollars = ((double) val()) * value;
        }

        CURRENCY operator/(T value)
        {
            this->p_iDollars = ((double) val()) / value;
        }

        CURRENCY operator= (int value)
        {
            this->p_iDollars = value;
        }

        double val()
        {
            return this->p_iDollars + ((double) this->p_iCents / this->p_iPrecision);
        }

        int dollars()
        {
            return this->p_iDollars;
        }

        int cents()
        {
            return this->p_iCents;
        }

};
```

I want to be able to implement this class as a type like:

```
typedef CURRENCY<double> money;

int main()
{

    money m = 3.141592653589;

    m = m + 30;  // added assignment operator here

    cout << m << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

I guess I'm not sure how to even word what I'm describing other than I want to return the current "value" of my object knowing that the object doesn't really *have* a value.  I'm not sure how to allow my class to carry a default represented value that can be returned and manipulated.

In this case I would like `cout << m << endl;` to return my "new" value: `33.1416`.

Any direction would be helpful because I'm just trying to wrap my head around this concept. *Note: this code is super incomplete and not intended to be fully functional since I was experimenting but please feel free to correct any issues with logic or the direction I was going*

**I'm a dumbass and didn't include the assignment above...**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the `+` and similar operators doesn't actually modify the object involved in the operation, which means you must create a new object that you then return from the operator function.

Something like

```
CURRENCY operator+(T value)
{
    CURRENCY temp(*this);

    temp.p_iDollars += value;

    return temp;
}
```

Comment: That actually clears up some confusion when I was reading about that, thanks!

Comment: The better way to do this is to implement the `operator+=` as a member function and make the `operator+` a non member, but use the `operator+=` in `operator+`

Answer (score 1):

```
template<typename T>
ostream& operator<<(ostream& lhs, const CURRENCY<T>& rhs) {
  lhs << /*output rhs the way you want here*/;
}
```

Also it is very poor design to have operator+, operator/, etc modify the calling object. These should not be member functions and should not modify the calling object. Instead create a copy of the passed CURRENCY, modify that, and return it.